# Grabbing graphics data from Google Street View object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, applet, capture

As the title suggests, I have a Google Street View object in my web page.
My program 'drives' along certain routes, essentially, I control Google Street View's javascript API through an embedded Java applet (in the same page).

I need to be able to grab imagery from my current Google Street View panorama - I don't really care how.  If it can't be done using Google's API - I am totally fine with actually 'grabbing' the image from the  that contains the flash object - whether this is done using javascript or the Java applet, the graphical data will need to be ultimately delivered to the Java applet for processing.

What, if any, are my options?

Please note that I am not trying to save an image to the filesystem, nor am I trying to violate Google's terms of use - I am simply analyzing the image of my current position to decide on where I am...

Comment: Well, if you are willing to use **Java Applet** then this should be found at http://www.google.com/search?q=capture+screen+with+java+applet

Comment: First of all, toda gever.
Secondly, that's not exactly what I meant... I mean - I guess I could have my java applet capture the screen device's pixel data... but I need to get the pixel data for the contents of a specific div on my page.  Using your suggestion of screen capture, I would get an image of the entire screen which I will then need to 'cut' to only get the area I am interested in.  Unfortunately, unless there's a way to figure out where this box is rendered on the screen, it's difficult.  I need to programmatically grab the pixel data from a certain div on my page.

Answer (score 1):

Why not find the position of the div within the window (using javascript) then translate that by the position of the window on the screen (using javascript), and then screen scrape those bounds using java?

Seems ridiculous to me, but hey.... Its kind of a crazy question :)